# Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null. error

Tags: firebase, authentication, oncreate

so i have this error and ive looked through all the answers to this problem here on Soverflow and everything is correct ive checked internet gradle and firebase all as it should be can any one help. here is my Mainactivity code

```
package com.example.firebaseintronew;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListner;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private EditText email;
    private EditText password;
    private Button login;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailED);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordED);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = database.getReference("Message");

        databaseReference.setValue("Hello Spidey");

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                String value = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        mAuthListner = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

                if (user != null) {
                    //user is Signed In
                    Log.d(TAG,"User Signed In");
                }else {
                    //user is Signed Out
                    Log.d(TAG,"User Signed Out");
                }
            }
        };
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String emailString = email.getText().toString();
                String pwd = password.getText().toString();

                if (!emailString.equals("") && !pwd.equals("")) {
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailString, pwd)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed Sign In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                            .show();
                                }else {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Signed In!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                            .show();
                                    //we can now write to the database
                                    databaseReference.setValue("Hey I have Signed In successfully!!");
                                }
                            }
                        });
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListner);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (mAuthListner !=null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListner);
        }
    }
}
```

may something todo with my onclick listner as the code runs till i sign in and i get Failed sign in???

```
Logcat 

2022-01-21 14:36:57.313 12066-12066/? I/irebaseintrone: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2022-01-21 14:36:57.333 12066-12066/? I/irebaseintrone: Unquickening 12 vdex files!
2022-01-21 14:36:57.335 12066-12066/? W/irebaseintrone: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2022-01-21 14:36:58.329 12066-12066/com.example.firebaseintronew D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2022-01-21 14:36:58.331 12066-12066/com.example.firebaseintronew D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2022-01-21 14:36:58.408 12066-12066/com.example.firebaseintronew I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
2022-01-21 14:36:58.509 12066-12066/com.example.firebaseintronew I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2022-01-21 14:36:58.638 12066-12099/com.example.firebaseintronew D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2022-01-21 14:36:58.661 12066-12099/com.example.firebaseintronew D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2022-01-21 14:36:58.689 12066-12099/com.example.firebaseintronew D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2022-01-21 14:36:58.913 12066-12102/com.example.firebaseintronew I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to fallback implementation
2022-01-21 14:36:59.050 12066-12066/com.example.firebaseintronew W/irebaseintrone: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-01-21 14:36:59.051 12066-12066/com.example.firebaseintronew W/irebaseintrone: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-01-21 14:36:59.369 12066-12066/com.example.firebaseintronew I/irebaseintrone: IncrementDisableThreadFlip blocked for 14.861ms
2022-01-21 14:36:59.707 12066-12078/com.example.firebaseintronew I/irebaseintrone: Background young concurrent copying GC freed 28116(2164KB) AllocSpace objects, 4(80KB) LOS objects, 90% free, 2653KB/26MB, paused 2.404ms total 361.616ms
2022-01-21 14:36:59.717 12066-12066/com.example.firebaseintronew D/MainActivity: User Signed Out
2022-01-21 14:36:59.792 12066-12097/com.example.firebaseintronew D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf1d21a30, tid 12097
2022-01-21 14:36:59.810 12066-12097/com.example.firebaseintronew D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
2022-01-21 14:36:59.818 12066-12097/com.example.firebaseintronew W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2022-01-21 14:36:59.837 12066-12097/com.example.firebaseintronew D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xf1d21800: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2022-01-21 14:36:59.858 12066-12097/com.example.firebaseintronew D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf1d21800: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xf2054fd0) (first time)
2022-01-21 14:36:59.893 12066-12097/com.example.firebaseintronew I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
2022-01-21 14:36:59.896 12066-12097/com.example.firebaseintronew D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
2022-01-21 14:36:59.897 12066-12097/com.example.firebaseintronew D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf1d21720, tid 12097
2022-01-21 14:36:59.897 12066-12097/com.example.firebaseintronew D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
2022-01-21 14:36:59.897 12066-12097/com.example.firebaseintronew D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3f7ffe000 size 0x2000
2022-01-21 14:36:59.979 12066-12097/com.example.firebaseintronew D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
2022-01-21 14:37:00.688 12066-12097/com.example.firebaseintronew I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=879ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=20494155280307, Vsync=20494188613639, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=20494196005900, AnimationStart=20494196051400, PerformTraversalsStart=20494196112700, DrawStart=20494465848800, SyncQueued=20494495835600, SyncStart=20494627126800, IssueDrawCommandsStart=20494627501900, SwapBuffers=20494981930000, FrameCompleted=20495166150300, DequeueBufferDuration=5338900, QueueBufferDuration=2274000, GpuCompleted=72904454231491230, 
2022-01-21 14:37:00.793 12066-12066/com.example.firebaseintronew I/Choreographer: Skipped 63 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2022-01-21 14:37:00.809 12066-12097/com.example.firebaseintronew I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1082ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=20494205260273, Vsync=20495255260231, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=20495271890800, AnimationStart=20495271949500, PerformTraversalsStart=20495272221100, DrawStart=20495280027400, SyncQueued=20495280623000, SyncStart=20495280922500, IssueDrawCommandsStart=20495283986200, SwapBuffers=20495285249500, FrameCompleted=20495288016100, DequeueBufferDuration=878100, QueueBufferDuration=729900, GpuCompleted=43984843964424, 
2022-01-21 14:37:00.821 12066-12066/com.example.firebaseintronew D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 147798919; UID 10154; state: ENABLED
2022-01-21 14:37:01.217 12066-12102/com.example.firebaseintronew W/irebaseintrone: Verification of boolean com.google.android.gms.common.internal.IGmsCallbacks$zza.zza(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int) took 114.276ms (621.30 bytecodes/s) (1624B approximate peak alloc)
2022-01-21 14:37:28.802 12066-12066/com.example.firebaseintronew I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 1752 bytes, containing 1 windows, 9 views
2022-01-21 14:37:45.070 12066-12102/com.example.firebaseintronew W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
```

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: please see my logcat above im new to this so my understanding is not from much experience but i am getting there.